# linq create average from different columns

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am having a simple table with 5 columns

```
id
id_user
col1
col2
col3
```

how can make Linq query to select an id_user and sum up all the col1, col2, col3 integers to make an average of those 3 columns ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have your table something along these lines should do it:

```
from row in table
let avgTotal = (new [] {row.col1, row.col2, row.col3}).Average()
select new {row.user_id, avgTotal}
```

Comment: Hi Joanna, thanks for your help, I tried the code, however, the Avg() function is not recognised by the compiler ?

Comment: @dtjmsy - it was a mistake on my part - I've corrected the answer now, sorry about that

Comment: Hi Joanna, awesome, thousands thanks, I didn' t know about the let command before this. It works perfectly, thanks again :)